# Word - Extract picture 'alt text - description'

Tags: microsoft-word, images, vba

I have a word document with 500+ embedded images.

For each image in the document, I want to get the 'Description' from the 'Alt text' section of the image (when you right click on an image>properties>alt text you can see this)

I then want to put that alt text below the image as normal text.

Is there a way I can do this with a vb macro in word?

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Word VBA macro to insert alternative text below images

```
Sub InsertAltTextBelowImages()

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Type = msoPicture Then
            ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).ConvertToInlineShape
        End If
    Next i

    For Each img In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If img.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            img.Range.InsertAfter (vbCrLf & img.AlternativeText & vbCrLf)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

#### Two problems

1. Word knows two types of images: inline images and floating images. Floating images have no *range* property so Word doesn't know to which paragraph the image actually belongs. You can convert (`ConvertToInlineShape`) floating images to normal inline images. But this will mess up your layout
2. You cannot just insert text "below" as you said. What if there is no line below the picture? You have to insert at least two page breaks (`vbCrLf`) together with the alternative text. This messes up your Word layout again

---

See my comparison screenshots on how my macro effects the layout

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A vb macro can do everything a user can do, but it would be a huge undertaking getting this programmed.

I would suggest exporting your word document to a html document. Then you can edit it with a texteditor such as notepad++ and use clever search/replace actions with regex to change each image in one go to what you want. Then you can save it again, and load back the html doc in word to convert it back to a word document.

I bet this will make you do the job 10 times faster than writing a macro that'll do it.